Why doesn't this SMD LED work?
I recently designed a PCB featuring an LED (D3) wired to one of the STM32F405RGT6’s GPIO pins (configured as an output.) My goal was to have a simple "status LED" to confirm the microcontroller is functioning and can be programmed. After soldering all of the components, I uploaded a basic blink test, but the LED never lit.
Strangely, when I measure the voltage from GND to the LED_STATUS pin, I can see it oscillating between 0 V and about +3.22 V. Also, if I measure the voltage between GND and the LED-RES pin, the LED begins faintly pulsing. I tried swapping the blue LED for a red one and also flipping the LED’s polarity, yet the problem persisted.
Since I can verify the pin is indeed toggling, I’m led to believe the issue isn’t with the MCU or my code. The LED’s circuit is only the LED itself and a 1.5 kΩ resistor, so I’m unsure what else might be wrong.
Datasheet of the LED: datasheet







The entire schematic:

The PCB layout:




Are you sure that GND via is actually connected to ground?... sounds to me like it's not (impossible to tell from your screenshot which has lots of floating vias!) ... if it isn't connected, then this also explains why the multimeter made it start working (albeit very dimly)

What is the LEDs rated forward voltage? What current did you calculate based on 3.3v supply, Vf and 1.5k? (a rough guess is Vf=3.2v, and I=~66µA). Is that pin capable of output and driving enough current, and it's the drive strength configured correctly?

@Attie I've added a screenshot with the GND plane, the via is indeed connected to GND.

@Attie the Vf is Typ. 3.0V and Max 3.6V. Since it previously worked with the same configuration on another PCB, I thought I could calculate the current based on the Typ. 3.0V Vf, and I would get ~200µA, which the MCU can easily supply.  I haven't realized that the same LED from the same supplier could have different Vf. So I am assumming previously I was lucky and I got an LED with a Vf less than 3.3V and now I got one w=which has a Vf > 3.3V.

@Robert Can you add which MCU pin you used, and how you configured it? Maybe the pin is somehow special, and may need different initialization than more generic pins.

@Justme I used the PC13 pin of the STM32F405RGT6 and I configured it as a GPIO_Output.

@Robert That info belongs to the question. And PC13 is a bit special. Please show&tell how exactly you configured it as output. Did you code it yourself or let CubeMX generate the code for you? Show the code if possible. Did your previous project use PC13 or was it another pin, or PC13 on another MCU?

@Justme I've added screenshots with hopefully all the information about the configuration of the PC13 pin. I let CubeMX generate the code for me. Previously I used the pin PA0 from the STM32F103C8T6 MCU.

@Robert PA0 on F103 is not very special. It should have worked if 3.3V is enough for blue LED to begin with.

@Justme yes, it did work on the F103 MCU with the PA0 pin.

You are using pin PC13 to drive a LED, in a current source configuration.
The datasheet basically explicitly tells not to do that.
PC13, PC14, PC15 and PI8 are weak outputs, because their supply current goes through a power mux which selects between VBAT and main VDD supplies. These pins must not be used as current sources, datasheet gives an example of sourcing current to a LED.
The IOs have other limitations too, like max 30pF of capacitive load, and must not switch at higher rate than 2 MHz.
Later in the datasheet they say it's OK to source 3mA, but in another footnote they again say the pins must not be used to source current.
In addition to that, there may be other issues in the hardware or code, such as setting the pin mode incorrectly.
I am beginning to suggest that pin PC13 is set up accidentally to open-drain output mode, as it would explain why you see some togging and voltages and faint light from LED when multimeter is connected.
So at least the red LED should work, but blue ones generally are not driven directly from 3.3V IO pin as it might not be enough for a blue LED.

I just checked the datasheet, and you’re right: it specifically says PC13 shouldn’t be used to drive an LED. Although it notes that the pin can supply up to 3 mA, which should be enough in theory, this is likely the root of the problem.

@Robert it could be, but even directly shorting 3.3V via 1k5 resistor causes less than 3mA of current, so the problem must be in the code you do not show, or in the part of schematics you don't show, or the board has a manufacruring error and faulty in some way. The LED would still work even if not recommended. OK your code should work, it's push pull pin so it's good.

the board itself should be ok, because I ordered it from JLCPCB which is a very big PCB manufacturing company, so I doubt they would send a faulty PCB. Also, I designed another PCB a few months ago, which used the same MCU (STM32F405RGT6) with the same resistor and LED configured on the same pin and I ran into the same problem. Whit the other PCB I didn't try to fix the issue, because I thought the whole PCB is faulty, but now I really think it's because of the pin I chose.

Would it be a problem if I connect the LED to another free PIN of the MCU using a wire? Would that affect the PC13 pin?

@Robert Well I have had PCBs with broken or shorted trace so it's possible that PCB was faulty. But if you had exact same issue with completely different design and same MCU and same IO pin, there may be some mistake in the schematics, but we cannot confirm there isn't if you don't show them. Yes you can short PC13 to some other pin and drive it as long as PC13 is input.

I've added the entire schematic + the PCB layout in the post.

It sounds like either R7 is broken, one or both sides are unsoldered, or the connection to the ground plane is open (maybe a bad via).
Have a look at it under a microscope and replace it if it looks dodgy, or maybe even if it doesn't. If that doesn't work, jumper the end of R7 to GND with bit of wire-wrap wire.
Measuring across R7 essentially parallels 1.5kΩ with the DMM input resistance, so there should be no visible effect- but you are observing an effect.
It should go without saying that if it's actually a bad via (quite rare these days) the entire batch of PCBs is suspect, and the supplier should probably be put on probation or dumped.

Am I missing something obvious??  The 1.5K resistor only allows about 1 mA -- assuming a 5V DIO

@ScottSeidman 1mA or even 0.5mA should be very much visible with a modern blue LED. And certainly shouldn't change from no-light to some-light when you put a multimeter across the '1.5kΩ' resistor.

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany In that case, I’ll first replace the resistor and be sure it’s soldered correctly. If that doesn’t solve the problem, I’ll run a wire from the resistor’s ground pad to the PCB’s ground. Since I ordered the PCB from JLCPCB, the vias are likely fine, but if the issue persists, I’ll check them more thoroughly as well.

@ScottSeidman STM32 MCUs have never had 5V DIO so it's not a very good assumption it has 5V DIO.

@Justme I guess you could use a 5V-tolerant pin in an open-drain manner if you wanted.

If we're talking about a 3.3V DIO, the current will be way less than 0.5 mA.

@ScottSeidman About 0.6mA by my reading with a Würth 465nm 0603 blue LED - using the load-line method and 1.5kΩ.

The question Color LEDs and voltage: why the discontinuity on blue? has the following table which was taken from the datasheet:

:

While this question doesn't give the part number of the blue LED, an output voltage of +3.22 V from the GPIO will most probably be too low to light a blue LED.
The referenced question has tables of forward voltages for different colours of LEDs, which could be useful to select a LED for use with the GPIO output of a 3.3 V microcontroller.

The thing that puzzles me is, a few months ago I built another PCB that has the same blue LED and the same resistor and it works. Not only that, but when I measure the voltage across the LED on the PCB that works, the voltage at the highest point while pulsating is ~ +2.6V, less than +3.2V on the PCB that doesn't work. Also, I changed the blue LED with a red one and it still wouldn't blink even dimly.

@Robert It the red LED also doesn't work, then the other answer probably explains the issue. The example datasheet I found shows 0.3 V difference between the typical and maximum blue LED forward voltages, so there could be part-to-part variations meaning a blue LED doesn't always light reliably when driven from a 3.3 V GPIO port.
